# How to fix to pass YourKit -agentpath to docker ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, deployment

i am setting up the YourKit Profiler for docker deployment modules, which are deployed in linux server.

i tried to pass the -agentpath variable during ENTRYPOINT. I am using docker specific yourkit version suggested by yourkit.

Docker run
`docker run -d -p 1234:9080 -p 10001:10001 --name appName`

Docker entry point
`ENTRYPOINT java -agentpath:./YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=port=10001,listen=all -Xms256M -Xmx2048M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dspring.config.location=/configPath/appName.properties -jar /ngcdeploy/appName.war`

I am expecting the docker container to start and publish the yourkit profiles with provided port 10001.

But, the actual result, the container is not up if i use 
`-agentpath:./YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=port=10001,listen=all`
without above configuration, the container is bring up the module.

how to configure or setup the -agentpath: in docker entry point

Comment: Does this file `/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so` exists in docker container?

Comment: **YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker** is downloaded and kept in the same folder along with **Dockerfile**

Since the yourkit is in the current folder. i am calling `-agentpath` as below

`ENTRYPOINT java -agentpath:./YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=port=10001,listen=all`

Comment: just keeping YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker is same folder as dockefile is not sufficient. You need to add this `COPY /path/on/host/to/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker /usr/local/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker` in `dockerfile`. So that it will be available inside container filesystem. And then -agentpath should point to `/usr/local/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker`

Comment: yes i followed the same and configuration completed with out any issue.. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: can you please accpet and upvote my answer, if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the yourkit profile is not present inside container.

Please follow the steps as mentioned below.

You need to add these lines in `dockerfile`

```
RUN wget https://www.yourkit.com/download/docker/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker.zip -P /tmp/ && \
  unzip /tmp/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker.zip -d /usr/local && \
  rm /tmp/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker.zip

# In case of alpine container add this
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

ENTRYPOINT java -agentpath:/usr/local/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=port=10001,listen=all -jar my-app.jar
```

Build and run the docker container

```
$ docker build -t myapp:v1
$ docker run -d -p 1234:9080 -p 10001:10001 --name appName myapp:v1
```

More info [here](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/docker.jsp).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. i was followed the same [link](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/docker.jsp).. 
but instead of downloading on fly, i downloaded **YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker** and kept in the same folder along with **Dockerfile** file

Since the yourkit is in the current folder along with **Dockerfile** file. i am calling `-agentpath` as below

`ENTRYPOINT java -agentpath:./YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=port=10001,listen=all`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to configure `YourKit` in docker by coping the `YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.1-docker` into docker container and configuring `-agentpath:`